# Filter out jobs applied for, and rejected, in last N number days

Tags: feature-request, stack-overflow-jobs

I applied for a job on Jobs and received a phone interview--I wasn't selected out of the 200 candidates, not surprising.  The following weeks, I was receiving my regular E-mail notifications/alerts for open positions, and the same company that turned me down was still being listed in those notifications, just different positions.

I went ahead and applied again, for different positions, and I was contacted personally, from the company, saying "please wait 12 months from your last interview before being considered again."  That would've been great to know before applying and tailoring my cover letter appropriately.

I suggest adding a field that the employer can add to their company profile that indicates how long rejected candidates have to wait before applying again.  Also, these positions should be hidden/filtered (with an option to show?) by those searching for jobs that have applied and got rejected with the last N days (specified by employer profile field), and hiding those open positions for the company in Jobs E-mail alerts.

Answer (score -1):

If you wanted to avoid seeing jobs or receiving emails promoting jobs from a certain company, you can dismiss it!

Once you dismiss a company page, we will not send you any emails featuring any jobs from that company.

You can dismiss a company from [the search results page](https://stackoverflow.com/jobs/companies) (just filter it by its name and a cross should appear on hover) or from the company page itself (on the bottom, you should see a button to dismiss it).

Comment: But it would be nice to apply again in 12 months, so should I put it in my calendar to remind myself to remove the dismissal for that company?

Comment: @Kcvin yes, you should visit the company page and undismiss it from there after 12 months, as we have no plans to build an automatic undismissal at this time.

Comment: @g3rv4 I've applied to over 100 companies in the past month.  It's not a great user experience to require people to remember which companies they've applied to and how long each company requires they wait before applying again.  It's something that could be easily automated.  A simple "snooze company for 3, 6, 12, etc. months" will do.